# Meaning of root:wheel

Tags: command-line, users, group, chown

What does root:wheel mean in the following?

> chown root:wheel myfile

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`root` is a user (the super user) and `wheel` is a group (of super users I guess).

```
chown root:wheel myfile
```

means making `myfile` belong to the user `root` and the group `wheel` (read `man chown` for more information).

Comment: `wheel` is typically the group with sudo rights (see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name))

Comment: Some Unixen do this for files which are to be accessed by system administrators. Typically these file will have a user:group of root:wheel and permissions rw-rw----. This approach has fallen out of favour, as it allows system changes to be too readily made in error (eg, `cd /etc; …; vi hostname` would succeed); rather the modern approach has system files owned by root:root and requires the use of the sudo command prior to successfully changing a file (eg, `cd /etc; …; vi hostname` would fail, only the more intentional `sudo vi hostname` succeeds).

Answer (score 8):

More specifically about the wheel group:It is a Unix group specifically intended for only those users who have rights to su as root.