# Why is Debian not creating the 'wheel' group by default?

Tags: debian, group

It appears to be [Unix tradition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name) that a wheel group is created automatically, but Debian (and children, naturally) doesn't do so. Is there a rationale somewhere? Where else have you seen this tradition discarded?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Some unix systems allow only members of the `wheel` group to use `su`. Others allow anyone to use `su` if they know the password of the target user. There are even systems where being in the `wheel` group grants passwordless root access; Ubuntu does this, except that the group is called `sudo` (and doesn't have id 0).

I think `wheel` is mostly a BSD thing. Linux is a mix of BSD and System V, and the various distributions have different default policies with respect to granting root access. Debian happens not to implement a wheel group by default; if you want to enable it, uncomment the `auth required pam_wheel.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/su`.

Comment: rhel has wheel group and also sudo, in which you can make whole wheel group passwordless. I'm not following your point sorry..

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.10, uncommenting this line does not restore the wheel group.  But, you can duplicate the "root" group in /etc/group `wheel:x:0:root` and modify the /etc/pam.d/su file as `auth required pam_wheel.so group=wheel`, (removing the comment before).

Comment: You need not create the `wheel` group to make use of the `sudo` group in its place for `pam` purposes. Just add `group=sudo` following the statement. e.g. to allow members of the `sudo` group to `su` without a password, simply uncomment/modify the line in `/etc/pam.d/su` as follows: `auth       sufficient pam_wheel.so trust group=sudo`

Comment: All true, and it exists in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but appears not to be the same as before.  `sudoers` is the way to control this now (September 2017).

Comment: @SDsolar This hasn't changed in Ubuntu: `/etc/sudoers` has always been the way to control root access. But since the default `sudoers` allows anybody in the `sudo` group to become root, you can control root access by managing the list of users who are in the `sudo` group.

Answer (score 19):

Because wheel is a tool of oppression! From `info su`:

> ## Why GNU 'su' does not support the 'wheel' group
>
> (This section is by Richard
>   Stallman.)
>
> Sometimes a few of the users try to
>   hold total power over all the rest. 
>   For example, in 1984, a few users at
>   the MIT AI lab decided to seize power
>   by changing the operator password on
>   the Twenex system and keeping it
>   secret from everyone else.  (I was
>   able to thwart this coup and give
>   power back to the users by patching
>   the kernel, but I wouldn't know how to
>   do that in Unix.)
>
> However, occasionally the rulers do
>   tell someone.  Under the usual `su'
>   mechanism, once someone learns the
>   root password who sympathizes with the
>   ordinary users, he or she can tell the
>   rest.  The "wheel group" feature would
>   make this impossible, and thus cement
>   the power of the rulers.
>
> I'm on the side of the masses, not
>   that of the rulers.  If you are used
>   to supporting the bosses and sysadmins
>   in whatever they do, you might find
>   this idea strange at first.

See also the [Debian Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch04.en.html#_why_gnu_su_does_not_support_the_wheel_group). Anyways, the `sudo` group is built in so who needs `wheel`?

Comment: I don't know the history, but I doubt this quote is the real reason why Debian doesn't implement the `wheel` group by default. (Debian's `su` does support the `wheel` group, it's just not enabled by default.) Anyway rms's reasoning might apply to MIT in the 1980s, but it doesn't apply to most places where not all users can be trusted and ubiquitous Internet accessibility means security needs to protect against attackers from all over the world.

Comment: Pretty good.  Hah.

Comment: For what it’s worth, this is pretty bad reasoning for this feature. Nowadays almost all devices have internet access, making them vulnerable to completely known third parties, and there any extra restriction caused by this kind of group would make sense.