# Is there disk-level caching in Solaris 11?

Tags: caching, solaris, partition, sparc, iscsi

I have an iSCSI disk at `/dev/rdsk/c5t6d0`

I have made a partition (slice with UEFI label) at: `/dev/rdsk/c5t6d0s0`

Now I write some data to the slice:

```
echo "xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy" >/text
dd if=/text of=/dev/dsk/c5t6d0s0
```

If I dump the disk contents I see the UEFI label and also my data at offset 0x5000:

```
dd if=/dev/rdsk/c5t6d0 bs=512 | xxd
0000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
...
0000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001b0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0eb5 7760 0000 00ff  ..........w`....
00001c0: ffff eeff ffff 0100 0000 ff3f 0300 0000  ...........?....
00001d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00001f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa  ..............U.
0000200: 4546 4920 5041 5254 0000 0100 5c00 0000  EFI PART....\...
0000210: 7187 d278 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000  q..x............
0000220: ff3f 0300 0000 0000 2200 0000 0000 0000  .?......".......
0000230: de3f 0300 0000 0000 fd59 3d67 51a0 4d13  .?.......Y=gQ.M.
0000240: abdd a5e8 8251 c7ac 0200 0000 0000 0000  .....Q..........
0000250: 8000 0000 8000 0000 7e8c 8e06 0000 0000  ........~.......
0000260: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000270: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
...
0005000: 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879  xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy
0005010: 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879  xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy
0005020: 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879  xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy
0005030: 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 7879 0ab6 db6d  xyxyxyxyxyxy...m
0005040: 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d  m..mm..mm..mm..m
0005050: 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d  m..mm..mm..mm..m
0005060: 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d  m..mm..mm..mm..m
0005070: 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d  m..mm..mm..mm..m
0005080: 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d  m..mm..mm..mm..m
0005090: 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d 6db6 db6d  m..mm..mm..mm..m
```

But If I do the same dump at storage side (iSCSI target), I do not see my data written!
I **shutdown** the SPARC/solaris machine and **voila!** the data is now there.

How can this be? Is Solaris caching my data in memory? How can I disable this?

Note1: I tried to use `sync` but it did not help and anyway it is related to files in a file-system, which I do not have in my scenario.

Note2: My machine is a T5220 UltraSPARC T2 Server with Solaris 11.3

Note3: 'storage' is an Ubuntu server with iSCSI-target on local disk backing-store.

Comment: Try to write with synchronous IO: `dd if=/text of=/dev/dsk/c5t6d0s0 oflag=sync` -- it should bypass page cache entirely.

Comment: It's also possible that the caching is being done on the iSCSI target server.  You haven't told us how you accessed the data on that server.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to the block device (`dsk`) which is buffered. Should you want to bypass the buffer, you might directly write to the raw device (`rdsk`, see [What are character special and block special files in a unix system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/what-are-character-special-and-block-special-files-in-a-unix-system) ) by running:

```
dd if=/text of=/dev/rdsk/c5t6d0s0
```

Your `/text` file would probably need to have a size exactly multiple of a block size for `dd` to succeed though.

Alternatively, you can still use the character device but tell `dd` to sync its output:

```
dd if=/text of=/dev/dsk/c5t6d0s0 conv=sync
```

or, if you want fixed width output records:

```
dd if=/text of=/dev/rdsk/c5t6d0s0 cbs=512 conv=sync,block
```