# Shell script to test the presence of character special and block special files

Tags: shell-script, filesystems

I have the following two files in my working directory:

`test.txt` and `img.jpg`

`test.txt` is a character special file

`img.jpg` is a block special file

Now I want to find if these files are character special files or block special files using shell script.

I have written the following two shell scripts:

First-

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Enter file name: \c"
read file_name

if [ -c $file_name ]
then
    echo Character special file $file_name found
else
    echo Character special file $file_name not found
```

Input:

```
test.txt
```

Output:

```
Character special file test.txt not found
```

Second-

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Enter file name: \c"
read file_name

if [ -b $file_name ]
then
    echo Block special file $file_name found
else
    echo Block special file $file_name not found
```

Input:

```
img.jpg
```

Output:

```
Block special file img.jpg not found
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're slightly wrong in your assumptions. Block special files are things like hard drive partition, memory devices. For instance, the main partition of my hard-drive is `/dev/sda1`. The test's (aka `[`) `-b` flag will work for that, but it won't work for a picture file, which is considered a regular file.

```
$ test -b ./Pictures/NOTEBOOKS/8.jpg && echo "It's a block device" || echo "Not  a block device"                                                                                        
Not  a block device
$ test -b /dev/sda1  && echo "It's a block device" || echo "Not  a block device"                                                                                                        
It's a block device
```

Character devices are things like tty and serial consoles. For instance:

```
$ test -c /dev/tty1 && echo "It's a character device" || echo "Not a character dev"                                          
It's a character device
```

And `stat` can tell you pretty much this same information, just in text form instead of exit status like `test` does:

```
$ stat --printf "%n\t%F\n"  /dev/tty1 /dev/sda1 ./mytext.txt ./Pictures/NOTEBOOKS/8.jpg                                      
/dev/tty1   character special file
/dev/sda1   block special file
./mytext.txt    regular file
./Pictures/NOTEBOOKS/8.jpg  regular file
```

What you should be doing is using `file` command, and checking its output:

```
$ file ./Pictures/NOTEBOOKS/8.jpg                                                                                                                                                       
./Pictures/NOTEBOOKS/8.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02, aspect ratio, density 100x100, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 750x750, frames 3
$ file /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: block special (8/1)
$ file mytext.txt
mytext.txt: ASCII text
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please view this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVi5o38NGi0&index=6&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_, I am learning shell scripting by following this online tutorial

Comment: Your answer makes my understanding crystal clear. However at the same time it means that the author of the above said tutorial is completely wrong.

Comment: @Sonevol I watched the video, found the part where they mention it at 7:22. Yep, the author of the video is wrong. A picture or video file is still considered regular file, it is not block file.  A text file with words in it is not character file. Character file (or more commonly, character devices) read characters, so say I have Arduino or Raspberry Pi on `/dev/ttyUSB0` , and if I write characters there, those devices will read what I'm sending to them.

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest you read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60147/85039

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat test-c.bash 
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Enter file name: \c"
read file_name

if [ -c $file_name ]
then
    echo Character special file $file_name found
else
    echo Character special file $file_name not found
fi
$ bash test-c.bash 
Enter file name: /dev/tty
Character special file /dev/tty found
$ cat test-b.bash
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Enter file name: \c"
read file_name

if [ -b $file_name ]
then
    echo Block special file $file_name found
else
    echo Block special file $file_name not found
fi
$ bash test-b.bash 
Enter file name: /dev/sda
Block special file /dev/sda found
```

Except for the missing `fi` in your programs, they do what one would expect.

Your assumption...

> test.txt is a character special file
>
> img.jpg is a block special file

...probably is wrong if you have not created them to fulfil this e.g. using `mknod`.
(See `man mknod`.)

So if your test files are what the names are hinting to, they are just plain normal (regular) files.

What were you looking for?

A way to distinguish between text files and binary files like in DOSish operating systems?

This is a relict of CP/M days or even older. The filesystem did track the file sizes in blocks and therefor text files needed an end of file character to flag the end of valid text.

The consequence is, that concatenation of binary files and text files  has to be done differently.

Unixish filesystems track the file's size in blocks and in actually used bytes, so there is no need to flag the text end using a special end character.

If you want to guess what's inside a file, you can use the `file` command:

```
$ file 20170130-094911-GMT.png 
20170130-094911-GMT.png: PNG image data, 744 x 418, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
$ file calendar.txt 
calendar.txt: ASCII text
```

HTH!