# MITM / Proxy for Character devices

Tags: linux, android, character-device, character-special-files

I have a [character devices file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60034/what-are-character-special-and-block-special-files-in-a-unix-system), say /dev/X and I would like to capture every interaction which goes in and out of /dev/X.

I'm looking for a way to create some kind of MITM/Proxy to that file.

**Edit:**

Regarding what X is, it is FM interface over android. So /dev/fm is the character device file.

The end goal is to intercept any command that is sent to this file.

Comment: What kind of character device? Is it a (possibly emulated) serial line, a pty, ... If you know the specifics it helps a lot. You can add the additional information right in the question.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Hi, thanks for the response, I have edited my question.