# What is the significance of the "wheel" group?

Tags: linux, group

I've commonly seen references to a `wheel` user group online as well as when setting up my `sudoers` file.  Does naming a group `wheel` imply something special about the group or is it just a name for a generic group used in the same manner that `foo` and `bar` are thrown about?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1262/22565 I'd be tempted to vote it as a duplicate?

Comment: Whoever considers this question a duplicate may have missed the point. The linked question is about the _name_. This question is more about its _role_. I thought the difference was obvious.

Answer (score 51):

Rather than have to dole out individual permissions on a system, you can add users to the wheel group and they can gain access to administrator levels, simply by being in the wheel group. It's typically tied directly into `sudo`.

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

Which means you can do anything on the system with `sudo <cmd>`.

Previously you needed to be in the wheel group if you wanted to have access to use certain commands, such as `su`.

*excerpt - [Wheel on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(Unix_term))*

> Modern Unix systems use user groups to control access privileges. The
>   wheel group is a special user group used on some Unix systems to
>   control access to the su command, which allows a user to masquerade as
>   another user (usually the super user).

Comment: Why is it called "wheel"?

Comment: *The term was derived from the slang phrase big wheel, referring to a person with great power or influence.* [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(computing))

Comment: Here's an alternative thought I had: On a ship, one can pass "The Wheel" to trusted subordinates to man the ship. It also has significance in terms of control but also added responsibility i.e. the steering wheel of  car

Answer (score 11):

Early on in the days of Unix one had to be a member of `wheel` in order to su to root. Used as an additional layer of protection for the system. I don't know of any special significance now, it is just a legacy like the `uucp` group.